# Selectively set attribute of multiple inputs in a div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My divs include inputs of type select, text input, checkbox and various others

I have successfully managed to set the attribute of disabled for all elements in a div to `true` using the code below in jQuery.

```
$("#for_all_div1 :input").attr("disabled", true);
$("#for_all_div2 :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

My question is how can I set the attributes for all inputs in the div but skip the checkbox inputs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable all input except checkbox use `:not(:checkbox)`

`$("#for_all_div2 :not(:checkbox)").prop("disabled", true);`

Also, it's better to use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` for setting the disabled attribute.

**Demo**

```js
$("#for_all_div2 :not(:checkbox)").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="for_all_div2">
<input type="text" />
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: @DouglasHosea No problem, happy to help

Comment: p/s: You should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set properties, not `.attr()`.

Comment: @Terry true true, I just copied the op's example, must admit i didnt check the .attr. will change it.

Answer (score 1):

use  `.not()`

```js
$("#for_all_div2 :input").not("[type=checkbox]")
.attr("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="for_all_div2">
<input type="text" /><br>
<input type="text" />

<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```